# Python script to check bond status for Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I have the Below python code which I'm using to determine the Linux bond/team status. **This code works just fine**. I am not good at aligning the output formatting thus getting little hiccup.

I wanted the Printing Format into a Certain format, would appreciate any help on the same.

### Below is the code exercise:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Using below file to process the data
# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0

import sys
import re

def usage():
        print '''USAGE: %s [options] [bond_interface]

Options:
        --help, -h      This usage document

Arguments:
        bond_interface  The bonding interface to query, eg. 'bond0'. Default is 'bond0'.
''' % (sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(1)

# Parse arguments
try:
        iface = sys.argv[1]
        if iface in ('--help', '-h'):
                usage()
except IndexError:
        iface = 'bond0'

# Grab the inf0z from /proc
try:
        bond = open('/proc/net/bonding/%s' % iface).read()
except IOError:
        print "ERROR: Invalid interface %s\n" % iface
        usage()

# Parse and output
active = 'NONE'
Link = 'NONE'
slaves = ''
state = 'OK'
links = ''
bond_status = ''
for line in bond.splitlines():
        m = re.match('^Currently Active Slave: (.*)', line)
        if m:
                active = m.groups()[0]

        m = re.match('^Slave Interface: (.*)', line)
        if m:
                s = m.groups()[0]
                slaves += ', %s' % s

        m = re.match('^Link Failure Count: (.*)', line)
        if m:
                l = m.groups()[0]
                links += ', %s' % l

        m = re.match('^MII Status: (.*)', line)
        if m:
                s = m.groups()[0]
                if slaves == '':
                        bond_status = s
                else:
                        slaves += ' %s' % s

                if s != 'up':
                        state = 'FAULT'

print "%s %s (%s) %s %s %s"  % (iface, state, bond_status, active, slaves, links)
```

### Result:

```
$ ./bondCheck.py
bond0 OK (up) ens3f0 , ens3f0 up, ens3f1 up , 0, 0
```

### Expected:

```
bond0: OK (up), Active Slave: ens3f0 , PriSlave: ens3f0(up), SecSlave: ens3f1(up) , LinkFailCountOnPriInt: 0, LinkFailCountOnSecInt: 0
```

Comment: you can use `m.group(0)` in place of `m.groups()[0]`, and you might benefit from the `argparse` module if you are interested in an out of the box solution for command line help and options.. just my 2 cents .. also if you want those missing strings in your output,... hmm.. group 0 should be the whole string.

Comment: change the `m.groups()[0]` to `m.group(0)`. that should fix it

Comment: I need the output formatting changed rest the script works fine, formatting i'm not good.

Comment: you aren't getting the full text with your expressions because your'e expecting m.groups()[0] to behave the same way as m.group(0).

Comment: That's correct but then again this is getting other things mixed up like removing parens it gives `bond0 FAULT ('up',) ('ens3f0',) , ens3f0 up, ens3f1 up , 0, 0`

Comment: If you want to only extract the text like `'ens3f0'`, then keep the parens, and use `m.group(1)`, but also put the text around your output that you need like `"Active Slave: %s"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to format in a very basic way as shown below :

```
print "%s: %s (%s), Active Slave: %s, PriSlave: %s (%s), SecSlave: %s (%s), LinkFailCountOnPriInt: %s, LinkFailCountOnSecInt: %s"  % (iface, state, bond_status, active, slaves.split(',')[1].split()[0], slaves.split(',')[1].split()[1], slaves.split(',')[2].split()[0], slaves.split(',')[2].split()[1], links.split(',')[1], links.split(',')[2])
```

RESULT:

```
bond0: OK (up), Active Slave: ens3f0, PriSlave: ens3f0 (up), SecSlave: ens3f1 (up), LinkFailCountOnPriInt:  1, LinkFailCountOnSecInt:  1
```

However,  I would suggest to get the values into variables prior and then use them in the print statement so as to avoid "out of index" issues during print() , as in rare cases like bond with only one interface will report indexing error while splitting hence good to get the values in variable and suppress the out of index into exception for those cases.

Comment: Thanks, @pynix :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the way with "/proc/net/bonding/%s' for querying bond status. It could trigger system panic. Try to use "/sys/class/net/bondX/bonding", it is more safe.